# 3d Cube clock css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, time

This is Cube clock on html/css/javascript. How to make the seconds on the secondCube updating on the left side of the cube, and on the remaining sides of the cube these updated seconds are frozen? Here is an example to make my idea clear to you: the seconds is updated on the left invisible side of the cube, the cube makes a full circle around its axis - at this time the  current seconds is frozen, then the seconds is updated again on the left invisible side (see gif image example)[GIF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrLj2.gif)

```js
function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date();



  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();
  var second = now.getSeconds();

  // Extract the last digit of the hour, minute, and second
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;

  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;

  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;

}

// Initial call to display the time when the page loads
updateClock();

// Update the clock every second
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.clock-container {
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation-duration: 3.5s;
  /* Adjust the value for the desired rotation speed */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  /* Adjust the font size */
  font-family: 'Your Chosen Font', sans-serif;
  /* Specify the desired font */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
  border: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
  border-radius: 8px;
  filter: blur(0.7px);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#hourCube {
  animation-name: rotateHour;
  left: -130%;
  height: 0%;
}

#minuteCube {
  animation-name: rotateMinute;
}

#secondCube {
  animation-name: rotateSecond;
  left: 130%;
  top: -100px;
}

.face.front {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
  border: -1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /* Edge color */
}

.face.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

@keyframes rotateHour {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateMinute {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateSecond {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>3D Digital Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clock-container">
    <div class="cube" id="hourCube">
      <div class="face front">0</div>
      <div class="face back">0</div>
      <div class="face top">0</div>
      <div class="face bottom">0</div>
      <div class="face left">0</div>
      <div class="face right">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cube" id="minuteCube">
      <div class="face front">0</div>
      <div class="face back">0</div>
      <div class="face top">0</div>
      <div class="face bottom">0</div>
      <div class="face left">0</div>
      <div class="face right">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cube" id="secondCube">
      <div class="face front">0</div>
      <div class="face back">0</div>
      <div class="face top">0</div>
      <div class="face bottom">0</div>
      <div class="face left">0</div>
      <div class="face right">0</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is also one bug here: on the die that shows the minutes, sometimes the numbers are shown upside down, is there a way to fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C5w0.jpg)

I want to update the seconds on the sides of secondCube only when the rotation angle is (for example) exactly -90 degrees and freeze the update until it reaches -90 degrees again. I tried this code but it is not working:

```js
function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date();

    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();

    // Function to get the current rotation angle of the secondCube
    function getRotationAngle(cubeId) {
        var cube = document.getElementById(cubeId);
        var st = window.getComputedStyle(cube, null);
        var tr = st.getPropertyValue("transform");
        var values = tr.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].split(",");
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
        return (angle < 0 ? angle + 360 : angle); // Convert negative angles to positive
    }

    // Update the clock content only when the rotation angle is precisely -90 degrees
    var rotationAngle = getRotationAngle("secondCube");

    if (rotationAngle == 90) {
        document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
        document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
        document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
       document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
        document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
       
    }

   
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
    
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;

   
  
}

// Initial call to display the time when the page loads
updateClock();

// Update the clock every second
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Comment: `"sometimes the numbers are shown upside down"` but the numbers would be read correctly(left to right) if your viewpoint was different (ie: above) ~ it seems that every 4th face on the middle cube has different text-orientation

Comment: `sometimes the numbers are shown upside down` it's on one face, always the same face, surely that's easy to debug - the hours cube also is buggy

Comment: `#minuteCube .face.back { transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(50px); }` fixes your 180 degree rotated face

Comment: As for the updating of time on the `seconds` cube it is hard to determine what the problem is - the numbers appear to update in unison

Comment: "the numbers appear to update in unison" yes, this is problem - the numbers should not update in unison, the numbers must be update only on one left side of cube and then stay freeze while cube will turn (see GIF image example and you understand my idea)

Comment: Just a tiny bit of advice here. I think there are great ways to make your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), which makes it less likely to get errors. For example by looping through the elements instead of selecting them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things easier to see, I added a green background color to the front face and red and yellow colors to the back faces. As mentioned in the comments, the back face of the minute cube is rotated, so this has been fixed with:

```css
    #minuteCube .face.back {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(50px);
    }
```

To achieve changing the seconds sequentially on the third cube (i.e. the "seconds" cube), I added `if` statements before rendering each face, so that each face will only be rendered every fourth call to the `updateClock()` function.

I also changed the length of the animation from 3.5 seconds to 4.0 seconds. This means that the cubes are rotating in 4.0 seconds.

With these changes, it is now possible to achieve the effect you wanted. However, it appears to be dependent on when exactly you start the animation. Most of the time (about 90 percent of the time), the seconds will change on the back face and so the actual change will not be noticeable, however, occasionally, the change occurs on the third cube on the rightmost face and is noticeable.

The same problem occurs with synchronizing the changing of the minutes from `59` to `00`, so I added appropriate `if` statements there too.

I suspect that the above synchronization problem may be connected with the way that `setInterval` works, but hopefully this solution can give you some more ideas to work from.

As mentioned in the comments, the code could be refactored (i.e. DRY) but I have not done this.

```js
function updateClock(firstTime = false) {
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();
  var second = now.getSeconds();

  // Extract the last digit of the hour, minute, and second
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;
  document.getElementById("hourCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + hour;

  if (firstTime) {
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  }

  if (second % 4 === 0)
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  if (second % 4 === 1)
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".top").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  if (second % 4 === 2)
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;
  if (second % 4 === 3)
    document.getElementById("minuteCube").querySelector(".bottom").innerText = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;

  if (firstTime) {
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  }

  if (second % 4 === 0)
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".front").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  if (second % 4 === 1)
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".left").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  if (second % 4 === 2)
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".back").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
  if (second % 4 === 3)
    document.getElementById("secondCube").querySelector(".right").innerText = (second < 10 ? '0' : '') + second;
}

// Initial call to display the time when the page loads
updateClock(true);

// Update the clock every second
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.clock-container {
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation-duration: 4.0s;
  /* Adjust the value for the desired rotation speed */
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  /* Adjust the font size */
  font-family: 'Your Chosen Font', sans-serif;
  /* Specify the desired font */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
  border: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
  border-radius: 8px;
  filter: blur(0.7px);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#hourCube {
  animation-name: rotateHour;
  left: -130%;
  height: 0%;
}

#minuteCube {
  animation-name: rotateMinute;
}

#secondCube {
  animation-name: rotateSecond;
  left: 130%;
  top: -100px;
}

.face.front {
  transform: translateZ(50px);
  border: -1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: green;
  /* Edge color */
}

.face.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(50px);
  background: yellow;
}

#minuteCube .face.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(180deg) translateZ(50px);
  background: red;
}

.face.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

.face.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(50px);
}

@keyframes rotateHour {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateMinute {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateSecond {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clock-container">
  <div class="cube" id="hourCube">
    <div class="face front">0</div>
    <div class="face back">0</div>
    <div class="face top">0</div>
    <div class="face bottom">0</div>
    <div class="face left">0</div>
    <div class="face right">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cube" id="minuteCube">
    <div class="face front">0</div>
    <div class="face back">0</div>
    <div class="face top">0</div>
    <div class="face bottom">0</div>
    <div class="face left">0</div>
    <div class="face right">0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cube" id="secondCube">
    <div class="face front">0</div>
    <div class="face back">0</div>
    <div class="face top">0</div>
    <div class="face bottom">0</div>
    <div class="face left">0</div>
    <div class="face right">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```